# vscode: Const value underlined red

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

```
type="module"> const response = await fetch("/lookup/" + 'user input').then(result =>result.json())
```

The const value is being underlined red by VS code, and I cannot determine the issue. Any advice?

My code does not run as expected, as it does not return a response from my backend on the front end when searched

Here is a photo of what VS code is telling me, but no 'major' errors?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any extensions in vscode..? does the code run as expected? please share a screenshot

Answer (score 4):

replace:

```
<script>

type="module">
```

by:

```
<script type="module">
```